# Pandas dataframe grouping time-series data

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Have a time-series data set as below

```
TimeR               Blower
2020-04-01 11:20:00 163
2020-04-01 11:20:00 164
2020-04-01 18:40:00 163
2020-04-01 18:40:00 164
2020-04-03 22:00:00 5
2020-04-03 22:00:00 7
```

..

I want output as

```
TimeR               Blower
2020-04-01 11:20:00 163,164
2020-04-01 18:40:00 163,164
2020-04-03 22:00:00 5,7
```

May please guide

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
df.pivot_table(columns="TimeR",values="Blower",aggfunc=lambda x:",".join(x.astype(str))).T.reset_index()
```